# Java MusicPlay in different Instance

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, audio-player

I have a Main Class with a MusicPlayer. It plays Music. Now I need to Stop and Play the Music in another class.

```
public class Main{

    public final Media musicMedia = new Media(new File("music.mp3").toURI().toString());
    public final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(musicMedia );

    public static void main(String[] args){
    }

}
```

So now, I want it like this: If the music is playing and I click the Button, the music shoult stop playing. And if it doesn't play the music and I press the Button, it should start playing the music. I hope you unserstand my issue.

```
public class AnotherClass{

    Main mp3 = new Main();
    boolean clicked = true;

    public void musicButtonClicked(ActionEvent e){
        if(clicked){
            mp3.mediaPlayer.stop();  //Stop doesn't work!
            clicked = false;
        }else{
            mp3.mediaPlayer.play(); //It starts to play the music, even if it is already playing. So it plays multiple times..
            clicked = true;
        }
    }

}
```

And I want to repeat the music after it finished.

Hope someone could help me with this issue!

EDIT: This is how I open "AnotherClass".

```
StackPane stockPane = FXMLLoader.load(Resource.onClassPath("AnotherClass.fxml").getURL());
root.getChildren().setAll(stockPane);
```

`AnotherClass.java` is the Controller-Class of `AnotherClass.fxml`.

Comment: Do you use multiple instances of `AnotherClass`? (I'm pretty sure you do... Anyways you need to add the code using `AnotherClass.musicButtonClicked`)

Comment: No, AnotherClass is actually a GUI class. Either it is opened or closed.

Comment: Add the code you use to access `AnotherClass`. "GUI class" is not a sufficient to determine how it's used

Comment: @fabian Done! Check out my edited Version. :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem with a fxml i created. (The media does not start on the first button click, since `clicked` is set to `true`, but the second click starts the music, the third one stops it, the fourth click starts playing the music again...). Do you create a different instance of `Main` somewhere else and use it to start the music? (You can easily check this by printing something to the console from an initializer: add `{ System.out.println("new Main instance created"); }` to the class body of `Main`; of course you could also add a break point for debugging...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Player static to you don't instantiate it twice or more.

```
public class Main {

    public static final Media musicMedia = new Media(new File("music.mp3").toURI().toString());
    public static final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(musicMedia );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

}
```

You don't need your own boolean to toggle stop/play. Just use the MediaPlayer.Status. Also implement `javafx.fxml.Initializable` for the first test if music is playing.

```
public class AnotherClass implements Initializable {

    private static boolean firstTime = true;
    MediaPlayer mp3 = Main.mediaPlayer;

    @FXML
    private Button musicButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        if (firstTime)
        {
            mp3.statusProperty().addListener((o, oldVal, newVal) -> updateButton(newVal));
            firstTime = false;
        }
        updateButton(mp3.getStatus());
    }

    @FXML
    public void musicButtonClicked(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
        switch(mp3.getStatus()) {
            case PLAYING:
                mp3.stop();
                break;
            default:
                mp3.play();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void updateButton(MediaPlayer.Status status)
    {
        switch(status) {
            case PLAYING:
                this.musicButton.setText("Stop Music");
                break;
            default:
                this.musicButton.setText("Play Music");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> I want to repeat the music after it finished

Set the CycleCount of the MediaPlayer to INDEFINITE.

```
mp3.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
```

> It starts to play the music, even if it is already playing. So it plays multiple times..

My guess is that you somehow managed to call `root.getChildren().setAll(stockPane);` multiple times; or it gets called again everytime something happens (maybe on a Button or Tab click - is your Application organized in Tabs?). Calling this multiple times will result in overlapping buttons and new Instances of the MediaPlayer which are not playing at the time they are instantiated - so a click on the stop/play button won't stop the old MediaPlayer, but start the new one.

Comment: There are tweo problems. 'Status.PLAYING' is not working. I imported Status from MediaPlayer, but it tells me that 'Status cannot be resolved to a variable'. And I think you misunderstood me with "multiplay times". So, the "stop" funcion doesn't work. And if I press the Button again, it starts palying again, if if the old one is still palying. Thats what I was meaning with multiple times.. :D

Comment: I solved the first problem. Now this is the problem: Lets say I click the button. The music starts. I leave "AnotherClass" to enter another class. If I come back to "AnotherClass" and click the button, it starts palying again and doesn't stop the first playing. Hope you understand..

Comment: Try `MediaPlayer.Status.PLAYING` instead and import just `import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;`

Comment: What do you mean "leave" and "come back"? The method is called when you click the button, right? And each time it gets called, it accesses the same MediaPlayer called "mp3" declared as `final` in your Main class, so it is not possible for "mp3" to ever contain or instantiate a different MediaPlayer than its first one.

Comment: @Zauvue *"Leave and come back"* probably means reloading the scene from the fxml which creates a new controller (`AnotherClass`) instance which in turn creates a new `Main` instance with different `Media` and `MediaPlayer` instances.

Comment: Well, like I mentioned "AnotherClass" is just a Scene. I can leave this Scene and go to another Scene. After that, I can come back to "AnotherClass"-Scene and want to disable the music. "AnotherClass" is actually the SettingScene in my Program. And I want to disable the "background-music" with the Button. So if I leave the SettingsScene to go back to the Main Program and decide than to disable the Music, I need to go back to the SettingsScene. And now the Music should be disabled if I click the button. But is just starts playing again, while it is already plaing.. Hope you can understand me.

Comment: Okay, so a workaround for your problem would be to set `Media musicPlayer` and `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer` to static and access it via `Main.mediaPlayer`. But this does not solve the root cause of your problem. There is a flaw in your design - Controllers should never be instantiated twice.

Comment: Thank you guys, it works!! But a last problem.. :D
If the Music is Playing, the Text of the Button should be "Music Off" to turn off the Music. If the music is off, the text should be "Music on" to enable it. I did that in the swtich/case. But if I open the Scene, the Text is automatically set to "Music on". How can I add a if/else Method, which checks on the start, if the Music is Playing and then change the text of the Button? I tried with a main, but then I need to set the Button to static and this causes a lot of troubles and errors..

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox I get an Error in the "updateButton()" Method. What do I have to enter in "URL location"? =/

Comment: @Zauvue what do you mean enter? You don't have to call the method! JavaFX does that for you when initializing the controller. Just ignore the URL and ResourceBundle. It's just there so it fits the method signature. Also please notice how the listener should only be set once (accomplishing this with the firstTime boolean)

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox So, I just write it down like you. But I get this error: "URL cannot be resolved to a type"
So I thought I need to change something. I didn't changed anythign till yet.

Comment: @Zauvue `import java.net.URL;` and `import java.util.ResourceBundle;`

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox I did this too. But then I get this error: "The method initialize(URL, ResourceBundle) of type SettingsSceneController must override or implement a supertype method"
And if I remove "Override" I can compile it but it doesn't work if I start the Scene.. =/

Comment: @Zauvue Yes, you have to write `public class AnotherClass implements Initializable` and `import javafx.fxml.Initializable;`

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox Thank you. I am sorry for being so stupid xD I am a bloody beginner. Everything works perfectly. THANKS!

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox Unfornatley there is another problem. If I use `getFile` to get the mp3 I can't create a jar file. I get the error, that the mp3 couldn't be found if I try to launch the .jar-File. I need to use `Resource.onClassPath`. But therefor I need a try/catch exception. This is only possible in a method..
But I can't write that in a method, because I need to reach it from another class. Do you have any ideas what I could do..?

Comment: @Zauvue try this https://gist.github.com/ImpulseTheFox/da374f2080f9dc2039a1de70f86c2450 :) If you have Telegram, you can send me a message there if you'd like.

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox Perfect, everything works now! Thanks! :)